# Why is everything pink?

Tags: texturing

I downloaded my old Blender project from Google Drive which I made in Blender 2.81. Even though I put all procedural textures, everything is pink. The textures are somehow missing. This is how it looks. [image: This is how my project looks]

Comment: Maybe you also missing hdri? It could cast pink lights. Check world nodes

Answer (score 1):

You also have to change the path to the textures. Else the computer don't know where to find them. [image]

Comment: I only used procedural textures. Like vorinoi and musgrave and wave.